# macos: How do you read the accessibility's speech rate from terminal?

Tags: mac, terminal, text-to-speech

I'm doing this to change a value

```
plutil -convert json ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.speech.voice.prefs.plist -o - | python -c "import json, sys;d=json.load(sys.stdin);[x.__setitem__(-1, $1) for x in d['VoiceRateDataArray']];json.dump(d, sys.stdout)" | plutil -convert binary1 -o ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.speech.voice.prefs.plist -
```

Where `$1` is a number.

That allows you to set a custom speech rate.

Is there a way to check what I have set. For example I might want to change it in the future but before I do I might want to see what it is already set to.